# What are S3 default grantees "Any Authenticated AWS user" and "aws.(account alias)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3

What are the following default S3 bucket grantees?

Please give a scenario of when you can use it to help me understand.

Any Authenticated AWS user 
aws.(account alias)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Amazon S3 - ACL Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)

**Authenticated Users group** – Represented by http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers.
This group represents all AWS accounts. Access permission to ***this group allows any AWS account to access the resource***. ***However, all requests must be signed (authenticated).***

**All Users group** – Represented by http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers.
Access permission to this group allows anyone to access the resource. The requests can be signed (authenticated) or unsigned (anonymous). Unsigned requests omit the Authentication header in the request.

**Log Delivery group** – Represented by http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery.
WRITE permission on a bucket enables this group to write server access logs (see Server Access Logging) to the bucket.

### Why use "Authenticated User"?

You would use this to ensure access was not completely anonymous. This way you can still publicly host data, but only authorized individuals who have an AWS account to access it.

This may not sound very useful at first.

But, it can be used to track unique users better than completely anonymous web-requests. You can also use this to develop policies to block users who abuse your object access, which is something very difficult to do with completely anonymous requests.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused , how to I give only my users access ?

Comment: That can not be done using only ACLs "for just your users". Instead you should use either a bucket policy and/or IAM policy to provide/restrict access to specific users or groups of users.

Comment: ok thanks, I still have a lot to learn about aws , some things are a bit confusing

Comment: Does Authenticated users group involve any AWS account within my AWS organization or outside my AWS Organization (any global user with AWS account)? Reason for the ask is AWS Docs are little hard to digest the fact that the bucket ACLs are open to the world

Comment: Authenticated Users are ANY global AWS user with valid AWS credentials. And, not only those AWS associated with your accounts or organization. If you want to use Authenticated Users, it is most likely for the wrong reason. Typically you would want to use it to track usage or limit access per credential, something difficult to accomplish with anonymous requests.

Comment: Useful link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-bucket-policies-and-apply-defense-in-depth-to-help-secure-your-amazon-s3-data/